# will it be possible to publish a screensaver on the upcoming mac app store?

Tags: macos, app-store, appstore-approval

We are working on a stylish screensaver that we would like to publish on the upcoming mac app store. Do you think it will be possible to release a screensaver? We reviewed the [draft guidelines](http://stadium.weblogsinc.com/engadget/files/mac-app-review.pdf) but still not sure about it.

Thanks, Renaud

Comment: I sent an email to Steve Jobs asking this. He did not reply! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't. It requires the app to create files outside its area. There are plenty of restrictions in the App development guidelines which prohibit that.
I think you need authorisation for that which is also a recipe for rejection.

From June all apps has to be sandboxed which makes it even more impossible.

Answer (score 6):

I actually tried writing Apple and ask about this. Since the screensaver has to install files (or rather *a* file - itself) to a system location, and since it is not really an app you want to open at will, I figured there was a good chance that it's outside the scope of the app store. The reply from apple was just a generic reference to http://developer.apple.com/support/mac/ and http://developer.apple.com/programs/register/. I wrote them back and said that I didn't want to fork out the $100 for the developer program unless I knew the guidelines for screen savers. Their reply was: *"Please know that developers should be testing and developing their apps in line with the Mac Developer Program License Agreement and the App Store Review Guidelines.
Should you have any questions or concerns, we request that you review the Mac Developer Program License Agreement details with your own legal counsel.  If you choose to enroll in the Mac Developer Program, you will have the ability to review the Mac Developer Program License Agreement before purchasing the program."*
Thanks a lot Apple, I'll review your reply with my legal counsel.

ps. I know this doesn't really answer your question, but at least it tells you not to waste time trying to ask Apple about it. If you do find an answer, I'd be very interested to know about it.

Comment: Thanks testers. You're right about problems because of installing a file to a system location (even a user folder location). We don't have an answer yet...

Comment: Wow that answer from Apple gave me a good laugh! Some people! Well I never.